# How to force release version in SAPUI5

Tags: release, sapui5

I am currently deploying my application to Hana Cloud and noticed that even though most of my files are loaded out of the `Component-Preload.js` file, the initiator still seems to be debug version of the library. For example `jquery-dbg.js`, `jquery.sap.global-dbg.js` or `ResizeHandler-dbg.js`. How can I force SAPUI5 to use the minified release versions of those file?

This is my script tag inside the `index.html`:

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-xx-supportedLanguages="de,en,da,fr,nl,ru,sv"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"example.ex": "./"}'>
</script>
```

Edit: Added my `neo-app.json` file:

```json
{
   "authenticationMethod":"none",
   "securityConstraints":[
      {
         "permission":"AccessApplicationDescriptor",
         "description":"Access application descriptor",
         "protectedPaths":[
            "/neo-app.json"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "cacheControl":[
      {
         "directive":"public",
         "maxAge":600
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open the app
- Open the *ui5 configuration* via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- unmark the debug mode checkbox

With the next load it will be in non-debug mode.

Comment: The debug-mode checkbox was already unchecked.

Comment: Is there any configuration left in the local storage? Try to clear it.

Comment: Sadly no change. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Any strange configs in neo-app.json?

Comment: Not really. Added it to the question

Comment: Do you use web ide?

Comment: No. I am using a local editor, while deploying via git.